# python: argparse, "prefix" or command before arguments

Tags: python, argparse

So I have a python script that looks like this:

```
def delete_something(item_id):
    ...

def create_something(name):
    ...
```

And I would like to use argparse to choose which function to be executed.

If I run:

```
$ python myfile.py delete --id=20
```

then the delete function should be executed, and if I run:

```
$ python myfile.py create --name="John Doe"
```

then the create method should be executed.

On the `delete` command, the `--id` is required and nothing else.
But on the `create` command, the `--name` is required and nothing else.

I thought argparse.create_group() would solve this for me but it did not.
What is the correct solution for this?

Comment: Can you post your `argparse` code? Did you use [`add_mutually_exclusive_group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group)?

Comment: If these arguments are required, they should not be options. Options should be optional.

Comment: Where did you see `create_group` documented?  Have you looked at `subcommands` (also called `add_subparsers`)?

Comment: How about writing a parser that recognizes `python myfile.py --delete=20` or `--create="John Doe"?  In other words combine the prefix with the required argument.